# UIImagePickerController with Blur effect

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, blurry, camera-overlay

I would to apply the blur effect to a CameraOverlayController.
I have found [FXBlurView project](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView). So, I have create a my UIImagePickerViewController and in the viewDidLoad I tried this code:

```
self.sourceType =
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        self.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
        self.allowsEditing = NO;
        self.showsCameraControls = NO;
        CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 480);
        UIImageView *overlay = [[UIImageView alloc] myFrame];
        UIImageView *testImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconExample"]];

        _blurView = [[FXBlurView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        _blurView.blurRadius = 6.0;
        _blurView.dynamic =YES;
        [overlay addSubview:testImage];
        [testImage addSubview:_blurView];
        self.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
```

But I have a problem... The result image is this...

[image]

in this image I see the correct icon green with blur effect ...but where there is blue color I not see the camera Image with blur effect...
some suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this tutorial should tell you what you need to know:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/60968/ios-7-blur-effects-gpuimage

He shows how using the GPU-Image framework, you can blur a real time video-feed

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but this approach won't work, the library relies on RenderToContext:, which won't work with the camera preview. Your best bet is to write custom camera code and blur it yourself.

See apple's Rosy Writer example code.